# Create a sub network via hardware

Tags: networking, router, ip, wired-networking

I'm trying to create a sub-network (B) to my home network (A). I prefer to use hardware instead of vlans so I got 2 routers. My set up is very much like in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/939362/setting-up-a-second-router-to-be-a-separate-network-on-a-home-networking-router) question.

My main router's IP is 192.168.1.1 and it's giving out 192.168.1.2-254 IPs.

My subnet router's ip is 192.168.10.1 and it's giving out 192.168.10.2-254 IPs respectively.

The problem is that network B can still access devices on network A. I was expecting that when I use the WAN port that wouldn't be the case and I'm a bit confused, what's the point of having a separate DHCP server and assigning an IP to the second router if the main network is still visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that network B can still access devices on network A. I was expecting that when I use the WAN port that wouldn't be the case

No, using the WAN port won't give you any sort of direct isolated line to the Internet. Your router B is connected *to network A* first and foremost.

(Also, router B actually thinks that network A is *part of* the "WAN", so as far as it knows, allowing packets to be sent netB→netA is a completely normal part of allowing LAN→WAN communications. The fact that network A uses private addressing (192.168.x) does not really mean much, as some actual ISPs unfortunately do the same.)

> what's the point of having a separate DHCP server and assigning an IP to the second router if the main network is still visible?

The point is that now you can configure the second router's firewall to allow or block packets in any way you like. For example, if you want to block packets from network B to network A, you can just add a firewall rule on B that literally does that.

Also, a router will not forward multicast and broadcast packets between two networks, which is relevant for Chromecasts and various other IoT devices which rely on multicast to "find" the device.

Comment: So there is literally no way for router B to have access to the internet through A *AND* no access to A's LAN without introducing software such as a firewall?

Comment: There isn't. Those are completely contradictory requirements, due to both networks having to share A's single Internet-facing hardware WAN port (i.e. "access to the internet through A") – eventually the packets will reach a place where forwarding decisions will be done by software.

Comment: As long as the router can forward packets between netA and WAN, and as long as it can also forward packets between netB and WAN, it will also be able to forward packets between netA and netB in the same way, subject only to packet filtering rules implemented in software. This would remain true even if you had an enterprise router where each port was its own network (instead of being a single ethernet switch as with most home routers) – they may have dedicated ASICs for doing the routing and filtering, but those still only follow rules defined by software.

Comment: So in order to achieve what I want without software I'd need a third router and put my current network A behind it, while my main router will only have WAN and the two other routers connected to it. This way networks B and C will not be accessible from within each other, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No, I would say you are still fully relying on software in this case -- mainly on the missing IP routing table entries. Better hope they remain missing. (And if e.g. router B simply gets a static route via A configured, whether out of malice or accident, then you will be relying entirely on router A's software firewall to protect network A. Been there, done that.)

Comment: Man you have no idea how confused I am right now.